# Getting the sum of two double parameters - Java

Tags: java, parameters, sum, numbers

Having a hard time figuring out the code neccessary to get the sum of the parameter.

```
public class SumOfTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        double number = sumCalc(5.2, 4.2); 
        System.out.println("Returned value: " + number); 
    }

    // Method here
}

Returned value:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you :)

BTW. I have been trying to work on it for more than an hour now. Tried many different things and I would've continued to try but I needed to complete this by a certain time. It's not like I'm taking the help and running, I'm saving it so I can get better so next time I won't have to ask you guys because apparently you're not friendly to people trying to learn Java. Thank you Codetector.

Comment: I wonder what's in class `Meth1`...

Comment: I wonder what course is this for....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a close look at some intro Java docs...
But here is your functions

```
static double sumCalc(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: I believe the hard time he is talking about is the 'static' aspect!

Comment: I believe the hard time is writing any code at all, since OP didn't even try to declare the method.